# How to redirect page with htacess without sending id

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have a problem with `.htacces` url-rewritting.

I have a folder called `dir` and in it I have three files

---

[image]

---

`.htaccess` is empty, `i.php` is empty too **but** in `index.php` I have

```
 $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM clients ORDER By id DESC LIMIT 10"); 
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){

        $url = "i/$row[id]/".preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9-_]/', '-', $row['company']);
        echo "<a href='".$url ."'>".$row['company'].'<br/ ></a>';

        }
```

When I hover over `echo` outputs a link like

`localhost/dir/i/101/today-in-news`

```
localhost // is localhost obviously
dir // is a folder where I keep index.php and i.php files
i // is i.php
101 // is the id of the news
today-in-news // is the title of the news
```

So, when I click on it, it takes me where I want, but I need to get rid of the id which in this case is `101` I want the link only to be `localhost/dir/i/today-in-news` when I click on it. I have tried everything I could, but failed without any result.

Comment: What are you wanting to do? Change the link that is outputted with the `echo`, or make it so that everything gets sent to the `i.php` file? Please clarify.

Comment: I need when you click on the links to take you to i.php but the url will not show the id of the page, only the title @MichaelWright

Comment: What is `i.php` going to do? Does it need access to the title as a query string parameter?

Comment: @MichaelWright  `i.php` should accept the `id` from that `index.php`

Comment: There is no way then to completely remove the `id` from the URL.

Comment: @MichaelWright then I have seem some news sites with url like `site.com/news/this-is-news-title` Where is the id then if you know anything trick that can get this done, that that is what I am looking for

Answer (score 1):

This code will pass that title through to `i.php` where you can then pull it from the database or whatever. Take a look [here](http://codular.com/htaccess-introduction) for some .htaccess information.

**index.php**:

```
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM clients ORDER By id DESC LIMIT 10"); 
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
    $url = "i/".preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9-_]/', '-', $row['company']);
    echo "<a href='".$url ."'>".$row['company'].'<br/ ></a>';
}
```

**.htaccess**:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c> 
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^i\/([a-zA-Z0-9_-])+\/?$ i.php?title=$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

**i.php**

```
$title = $_GET['title'];
```

Comment: thank, but when I got to `localhost/dir/index.php` it is giving me 500 Internal Server Error. I think, something is wrong with the htaccess code

Comment: Have done some minor tweaks to the htaccess. If the 500 has gone away, but the rewrite doesn't work, then it will indicate that your server doesn't have the required module installed.

Comment: It is not giving me anymore that error, but it is taking me to unfound page, error. All the modules are installed, and apache actaully works fine